# Use php as external javascript file in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I know that you can use a php file as an external javascript file like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.php"></script>
```

But how would you do this in CakePHP 2.0?

$this->Html->script('external_js', false); automatically adds the .js extension.

This page explains what I want to do:
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/04/03/blend-php-and-javascript-in-cakephp/

but it's out of date.  This method doesn't work with CakePHP 1.3+.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around the automatic addition of the .js extension by adding a question mark at the end of the filename. The Html->script function will add '.js' to any input that does not end in '.js' AND does not contain a '?'.

```
$this->Html->script('external_js.php?');
```